# Get current android device time, if it was set manually

Tags: java, android, time

The time received from android device by

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

provides current date with timezone, but if the time was changed manually on the phone (2 hours back, for ex.), it will not show it correctly

Comment: AFAIK I don't think you can get correct time if time was changed manually . For this you need to rely on Server.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way locally (on the device) to verify the validity of provided time.
But if your app requires internet connection or can afford it you should consider using a Web-API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to make sure your application's time is secure. Please check the following resource: http://julien-millau.fr/articles/Secure-Android-time-based-application.html

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want

Comment: Link-only answers are not that useful (even though the information linked to is), especially since links go stale more often than one might think. Please summarize the main points within the answer.